# API VK - проблема events в VKBotLongPoll

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, события, long-poll

**Проблема** возникает на строке

`for event in longpoll.listen():`

*Полный текст ошибки следующий:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Projects/VKbot/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    for event in longpoll.listen():
  File "F:\Projects\VKbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 285, in listen
    for event in self.check():
  File "F:\Projects\VKbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 262, in check
    return [
  File "F:\Projects\VKbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 263, in <listcomp>
    self._parse_event(raw_event)
  File "F:\Projects\VKbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 225, in _parse_event
    return event_class(raw_event)
  File "F:\Projects\VKbot\venv\lib\site-packages\vk_api\bot_longpoll.py", line 169, in __init__
    peer_id = self.obj.peer_id or self.message.peer_id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'peer_id'
```

*Полный текст моего кода:*

```
import constants
import ncov
import random
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


def send_message(text):
    vk.messages.send(
        random_id=random_id,
        chat_id=chat_id,
        message=text)


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='ЦЕНЗУРА')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk=vk_session, group_id='ЦЕНЗУРА')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

while True:

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.object.text:

            random_id = random.randint(1, 2147483647)
            chat_id = event.chat_id
            message_text = event.object.text.lower()

            if message_text.startswith('/'):

                if message_text == "/virus":
                    send_message(f'{ncov.get_virus_world()} &#128137;')

                elif message_text.startswith("/virus "):
                    country_request = message_text[8:]
                    send_message(f'{ncov.get_virus_country(country_request)} &#9762;')

                elif message_text == "/help":
                    send_message(
                        "/virus - Кол-во заражённых COVID-19 в мире &#128137;\n"
                        "/virus [страна] - Кол-во заражённых COVID-19 в стране &#9762;\n")

                else:
                    send_message(
                        "&#10060; Нераспознанная команда! &#10060;\n"
                        "Чтобы вызвать список команд отправьте '/help'")
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте какая версия API стоит в настройках сообщества. У меня по умолчанию стояла самая старая версия, после выбора последней версии эта ошибка исчезла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]