# Ошибка:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

```
import vk_api

from vk_api.utils import get_random_id

from toks import main_token

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

def write_message(sender, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : sender, 'message': message, 'random_id' : get_random_id })

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = main_token)

vk = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id = 193736173)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text') !="":
        reseived_message = event.message.get('text')
        sender = event.chat_id
        if reseived_message == "Привет":
            write_message(sender, "Добрый день")
        elif reseived_message == "Пока":
            write_message(sender, "До свидания")
        else:
            write_message(sender, "Я вас не понимаю")
```

Comment: Если у вас ошибка, то прикладывайте не только текст ошибки, но и трассу стека, чтобы было понятно в какой строке ошибке. Скорее всего, проблема в `reseived_message = event.message.get('text')` потому что `event.message` является `None`

Comment: Но а как решить проблему?

Comment: Для начала выполнить мою рекомендацию и выложить трассу стека. Когда у вас была ошибка там было несколько строк, вот все их и нужно приложить. А по поводу ошибки... странно, что у `event.message` может быть `None`, но раз так, то нужно добавить проверку

Comment: Пишет что ошибка тут(if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text') !="":)

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте проверку на `event.message`, если оно `None`, то условие не будет выполнено и код не дойдет до `event.message.get('text')`.

Пример:

```
from toks import main_token

import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


def write_message(sender, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': sender, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id()})


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=main_token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=193736173)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat \
            and event.message and event.message.get('text'):
        reseived_message = event.message.get('text')
        sender = event.chat_id
        if reseived_message == "Привет":
            write_message(sender, "Добрый день")
        elif reseived_message == "Пока":
            write_message(sender, "До свидания")
        else:
            write_message(sender, "Я вас не понимаю")
```

---

Посмотрел [пример из vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/a6884e6269f26dacc0ea39e6f38a535d7e5ecbcf/examples/bot_longpoll.py#L18) и увидел расхождение.

По тому примеру код должен был быть таким:

```
from toks import main_token

import vk_api
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


def write_message(sender, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : sender, 'message': message, 'random_id': get_random_id()})


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=main_token)
vk = vk_session.get_api()

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id=193736173)

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        reseived_message = event.obj.text
        sender = event.obj.from_id

        if reseived_message == "Привет":
            write_message(sender, "Добрый день")
        elif reseived_message == "Пока":
            write_message(sender, "До свидания")
        else:
            write_message(sender, "Я вас не понимаю")
```

---

**PS.**

Кст, для отправки запросов, можно использовать код, выглядящий более нативно:

```
def write_message(sender, message):
    vk.messages.send(chat_id=sender, message=message, random_id=get_random_id())
```

Comment: Он воще перестал работать не ошибок не выдаёт не отвечает на вопросы

Comment: @Артём, значит он и раньше не работал, т.к. я только добавил проверку `and event.message`, без которой скрипт все равно упадет с той ошибкой. Добавляйте print'ы в цикл, выводите значения из условия и проверяйте какое из них не соответствует ожидаемому. PS. посмотрел пример из библиотеки с `VkBotLongPoll`, обновил ответ

Comment: Теперь написано что def write_message(sender, message):
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : sender, 'message': message, 'random_id' : get_random_id }) тут ошибка

Comment: Мда,походу я ответ не найду лучше перепишу может она сама исправиться(Я ток начил изучать пайтон и много во ещё не понимаю и вы мне такие сложные вещи говорите я не могу понять что вы мне говорите если только будет пример то я сам буду разбираться что к чему а так по словам я не пойму)

Comment: @Артём, я не телепат и не могу сказать какая у вас ошибка :) Напишите ее текстом в комментарии. Кст, заметил, что get_random_id должна быть функцией, т.е. `random_id': get_random_id()`

Comment: вот ошибка (if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat and event.message.get('text') !="":
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get')

Comment: И ещё я переделаваю бота он раньше работал в лс и очень хорошо и я его изминил чтоб он работал в беседе и выходит ошибка ну крч раньше в лс работал а в беседе нет и я его изменяю

Comment: @Артём, я же ниже под первый кодом написал второй, который соответствует тому, что сейчас описано в `vk_api`. Там для получения текста используется `reseived_message = event.obj.text`, думаю, код откуда вы его взяли невалидный

Comment: Я его взял из ютуба глядел как зделать бота в вк и исправить эту ошибку и у того кто снимал видео в ютуб у него код работал идеально а у меня выходит ошибка

Comment: @Артём, а видео какого года? Я больше верю коду из библиотеки бота (ссылку на пример, есть в моем ответе)

Comment: 6 дней назад было видео снято

Comment: @Артём, возможно проблема в настройки API в группе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1097221/201445 . Кст, тот пример бота из либы: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/a6884e6269f26dacc0ea39e6f38a535d7e5ecbcf/examples/bot_longpoll.py#L18

Comment: Вот этот код работает https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/a6884e6269f26dacc0ea39e6f38a535d7e5ecbcf/examples/bot_longpoll.py#L18
но он мне не нужен мне надо чтоб бот отвечал на смс и команды выполнял, версия апи стоит 5.92

Comment: @Артём, если работает, то попробуйте вызывать `write_message` на полученный от юзера текст (у меня в ответе). Кст, версию api либы можно задавать в конструкторе VkApi: https://github.com/python273/vk_api/blob/c6f3f72fa0795b732cd673b26811affd7b6e58ca/vk_api/vk_api.py#L93

Comment: @Артём, в группе или в боте? Примите мой ответ и поставьте стрелку вверх

Comment: Хорошо в беседе бот работает